# Repeating XML element is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer

I tried to repeat XML element using a loop. It is working on other browsers. But it is not working in Internet Explorer. Anyone can solve this?

Here is the code.

```
var listStr="";
            list.each(function(index,item){
            listStr+="<li>"+item.innerHTML+"</li>"
            });

<ul>' + (listStr) + '</ul>
```

[Plunker:](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/42lR73391M3LWuZz?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that demonstrates your issue

Comment: @AkarshVijayan The link is added http://next.plnkr.co/edit/42lR73391M3LWuZz?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you face should be because of the .innerHTML/.outerHTML properties you use with the parsed XML element(s).

Since you are concerned about the text value, you should use [HTML DOM textContent Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)

```
list.each(function(index,item){
                listStr += "<li>" + item.textContent/*item.outerHTML*/+"</li>"
            });
```